# C++ Socket Part-4

Tags: c++, http, socket

In my ongoing attempts to become a better blog writer I have some written some more code that needs reviewing.

Full Source: https://github.com/Loki-Astari/Examples/tree/master/Version4
First Article: http://lokiastari.com/posts/SocketProtocols/

This code replaces the hand written socket code with a libcurl wrapper.

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Socket
    {

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Args>
int print(std::ostream& s, Args... args)
{
    using Expander = int[];
    return Expander{ 0, ((s << std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...}[0];
}

template<typename... Args>
std::string buildErrorMessage(Args const&... args)
{
    std::stringstream msg;
    print(msg, args...);
    return msg.str();
}

class CurlGlobal
{
    public:
        CurlGlobal()
        {
            if (curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL) != 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("CurlGlobal::", __func__, ": curl_global_init: fail"));
            }
        }
        ~CurlGlobal()
        {
            curl_global_cleanup();
        }
};

extern "C" size_t curlConnectorGetData(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);

enum RequestType {Get, Head, Put, Post, Delete};
class CurlConnector
{
    CURL*       curl;
    std::string host;
    int         port;
    std::string response;

    friend size_t curlConnectorGetData(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
    std::size_t getData(char *ptr, size_t size)
    {
        response.append(ptr, size);
        return size;
    }


    public:
        CurlConnector(std::string const& host, int port)
            : curl(curl_easy_init( ))
            , host(host)
            , port(port)
        {
            if (curl == NULL)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("CurlConnector::", __func__, ": curl_easy_init: fail"));
            }
        }
        ~CurlConnector()
        {
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }

        virtual RequestType getRequestType() const {return Post;}

        void sendMessage(std::string const& urlPath, std::string const& message)
        {
            std::stringstream url;
            response.clear();
            url << "http://" << host;
            if (port != 80)
            {
                url << ":" << port;
            }
            url << urlPath;

            CURLcode res;
            auto sListDeleter = [](struct curl_slist* headers){curl_slist_free_all(headers);};
            std::unique_ptr<struct curl_slist, decltype(sListDeleter)> headers(nullptr, sListDeleter);
            headers = std::unique_ptr<struct curl_slist, decltype(sListDeleter)>(curl_slist_append(headers.get(), "Content-Type: text/text"), sListDeleter);

            if ((res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers.get())) != CURLE_OK)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("CurlConnector::", __func__, ": curl_easy_setopt CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER:", curl_easy_strerror(res)));
            }
            if ((res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "*/*")) != CURLE_OK)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("CurlConnector::", __func__, ": curl_easy_setopt CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING:", curl_easy_strerror(res)));
            }
            if ((res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "ThorsExperimental-Client/0.1")) != CURLE_OK)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("CurlConnector::", __func__, ": curl_easy_setopt CURLOPT_USERAGENT:", curl_easy_strerror(res)));
            }
            if ((res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.str().c_str())) != CURLE_OK)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("CurlConnector::", __func__, ": curl_easy_setopt CURLOPT_URL:", curl_easy_strerror(res)));
            }
            if ((res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, message.size())) != CURLE_OK)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("CurlConnector::", __func__, ": curl_easy_setopt CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE:", curl_easy_strerror(res)));
            }
            if ((res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, message.data())) != CURLE_OK)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("CurlConnector::", __func__, ": curl_easy_setopt CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS:", curl_easy_strerror(res)));
            }
            if ((res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curlConnectorGetData)) != CURLE_OK)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("CurlConnector::", __func__, ": curl_easy_setopt CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION:", curl_easy_strerror(res)));
            }
            if ((res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this)) != CURLE_OK)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("CurlConnector::", __func__, ": curl_easy_setopt CURLOPT_WRITEDATA:", curl_easy_strerror(res)));
            }


            switch(getRequestType())
            {
                case Get:       res = CURLE_OK; /* The default is GET. So do nothing.*/         break;
                case Head:      res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "HEAD");    break;
                case Put:       res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);                   break;
                case Post:      res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                  break;
                case Delete:    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");  break;
                default:
                    throw std::domain_error(buildErrorMessage("CurlConnector::", __func__, ": invalid method: ", static_cast<int>(getRequestType())));
            }
            if (res != CURLE_OK)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("CurlConnector::", __func__, ": curl_easy_setopt CURL_METHOD:", curl_easy_strerror(res)));
            }
            if ((res = curl_easy_perform(curl)) != CURLE_OK)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(buildErrorMessage("CurlConnector::", __func__, ": curl_easy_perform:", curl_easy_strerror(res)));
            }
        }
        void recvMessage(std::string& message)
        {
            message = std::move(response);
        }
};

size_t curlConnectorGetData(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    CurlConnector*  self = reinterpret_cast<CurlConnector*>(userdata);
    return self->getData(ptr, size * nmemb);
}

    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    namespace Sock = ThorsAnvil::Socket;
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <Message>\n";
        std::exit(1);
    }

    Sock::CurlGlobal    curlInit;
    Sock::CurlConnector connect(argv[1], 8080);

    connect.sendMessage("/message", argv[2]);

    std::string message;
    connect.recvMessage(message);
    std::cout << message << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Did something go wrong with the indentation or is this on purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it a bit odd to use variadic templates and various tricks (`Expander`) just for concatenating a few strings in a beginner's tutorial. I would much rather see a function that checks for errors which would help eliminate all those `throw std::runtime_error(...)` from the main part of the class.

In your code, you use `unique_ptr<>` inside a method, but you choose to store a raw pointer as a class field (`CURL* curl`). Why? This will lead to bugs if your class is moved or copied as you'll end up accessing a disposed resource or try to clean it multiple times.

You declare `curlConnectorGetData` as `extern "C"` but only pass a pointer to it. The pointer doesn't care about name mangling. In the end you mention it 3 times (once as `extern "C"`, once as `friend` and once for the actual implementation which only delegates to a member function). All this can be simplified by using a lambda that doesn't capture (for which the C++ standard provides a conversion to function pointer).

You use the term `sendMessage` which I don't find quite appropriate for an HTTP request. The semantics of using HTTP isn't the same as using a simple socket for exchanging various messages. Users will quickly find the need to adjust various other parameters (like the request type which is currently hard-coded to `Post` (why not `Get`?)) and see the response as a more complex structure than just a string.

One more suggestion, I don't know if you're approaching this: try implementing input/output streams that read from/write to the sockets.

Comment: Unfortunately libCurl is a C library. So the callback function you pass must also be C (hence for correctness it **must** be an `extern "C" function` (which is not for name mangling but ABI compliance)). I will fix the other things. Especially the copy/move semantics. Thanks.

Comment: The streaming I will eventually cover in the blog but that is a couple of articles away. But I have already had reviewed objects that treat URL like std::istream objects. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/38455/507 and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/38402/507

Comment: All your comments have been addressed and uploaded: https://github.com/Loki-Astari/Examples/blob/master/Version4/client.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for not using raw pointer `CURL* curl` might be hypothetical memory leak. In `CurlConnector` ctor `curl` is initialized before `host` being initialized by `std::string` copy-ctor which might throw an exception. In such case `CurlConnector` ctor will not finish and therefore destructor is not going to be called.