# Fetching specific foreign exchange rates from fixer using curl and jsconcpp in C++

Tags: c++, json, web-scraping

I am trying to create my own algorithmic trading system using C++. I have searched the web for a nice tutorial for such systems and I didn't find any. Then I started to learn about `curl` and `jsoncpp` libraries and even documentation of those libraries are not made for a novice programmer like me. I mostly reused most of the code for creating this scraper especially `WriteCallback` function which I directly copy pasted from other C++ code without understanding it. I am sharing this whole code because someone else doesn't need to reinvent the wheel and can use this code as a template. Anyway this code is working properly (Ubuntu 14.04, CodeBlocks IDE, API: [fixer.io](http://fixer.io/)) and any kind of suggestion or feedback is welcomed.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

//writing call back function for storing fetched values in memory
static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}


int main(void)
{
  std::string readBuffer;


 //global initiliation of curl before calling a function
 curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );

 //creating session handle
 CURL * myHandle;

 // We’ll store the result of CURL’s webpage retrieval, for simple error checking.
 CURLcode result;


 // notice the lack of major error-checking, for brevity
 myHandle = curl_easy_init ( ) ;

 //after creating handle we ill start transfering webpage

 //curl_easy_setopt is used to tell libcurl how to behave.
 //By setting the appropriate options, the application can change libcurl's behavior.

 //CURLOPT_URL provide the URL to use in the request. Pass in a pointer to the URL to work with.
 //sample json output >> {"base":"EUR","date":"2016-07-22","rates":{"GBP":0.84108,"USD":1.1014}}
 curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP");

   /* send all data to this function  */
  curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);

   /* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */
  curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);

 //perform a blocking file transfer
 result = curl_easy_perform( myHandle );

 /* check for errors */
  if(result != CURLE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(result));
  }
  else {
    /*
     * Now, our chunk.memory points to a memory block that is chunk.size
     * bytes big and contains the remote file.
     *
     * Do something nice with it!
     */

    //std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;

    //json parsing
Json::Value root;   // will contains the root value after parsing.
Json::Reader reader;
bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse( readBuffer, root );
if(not parsingSuccessful)
 {
   // Report failures and their locations
   // in the document.
   std::cout<<"Failed to parse JSON"<<std::endl
       <<reader.getFormatedErrorMessages()
       <<std::endl;
   return 1;
 }else{
 std::cout<<"\nSucess parsing json\n"<<std::endl;
 std::cout << root<< std::endl;
 std::cout <<"Base = "<< root["base"].asString() << std::endl;
 std::cout <<"Date = "<< root["date"].asString() << std::endl;
 std::cout <<"Rate GBP ="<< root["rates"]["GBP"].asFloat() << std::endl;
 std::cout <<"Rate USD ="<< root["rates"]["USD"].asFloat() << std::endl;

 }

  }




 //End a libcurl easy handle.This function must be the last function to call for an easy session
 curl_easy_cleanup( myHandle );


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have some reviews that may help: 1) Convert Json From a stream into an object: [Json Serializer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11138/json-serializer) 2) Treat a socket like a stream [Socket Stream](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38402/stream-that-opens-an-http-get-and-then-acts-like-a-normal-c-istream) I have included simple instructions to set it up here: https://gist.github.com/martin-seomoz/723b790fdd8ac1d5b1b3eebd42124723

Comment: Can you please explain the advantage of using `ThorSocketStream` library.

Comment: Hello! Please don't make changes to the original post once it has been reviewed, as that invalidates the current answers. Please see our meta side on [performing iterative reviews](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) for more information!

Comment: @syb0rg What is the best way to add an updated code? Should I use answer post itself? should i ask this question in meta?

Comment: @Eka Read the meta post, and decide for yourself based on the options given

Comment: modified code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6d4ef79643696111fc62f16aa42d7895

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### These are C headers

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

You should probably use the C++ version (I hope you are not using C-String anywhere).

```
#include <strings>
#include <cstdio>
```

#### Header include paths

```
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
```

This should probably be `json/json.h` and you should specify the location where jsoncpp is installed with compiler flags.

#### Curl is a C library.

Therefore any callbacks should be C functions (not C++ functions). There is no guarantee in the standard thay they use the same ABI.

```
static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
```

Should be:

```
extern "C" size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
```

#### Never use C-Casts

C casts are hard to spot (in general). But also using C++ casts you can mark dangerious casts by uisng the appropriate cast.

```
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
```

I would use `reinterpret_cast<>` here. So that it is easy to spot and you intuitively know that this is a dangerous operation.

```
reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(userp)->append(static_cast<char*>(contents), size * nmemb);
```

#### Always check error codes.

All the following return an error code. You should validate these functions worked by checking this error code.

```
 curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
 curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP");
 curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
 curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
```

#### Prefer `"\n"` over `std::endl`

```
 std::cout<<"\nSucess parsing json\n"<<std::endl;
 std::cout << root<< std::endl;
 std::cout <<"Base = "<< root["base"].asString() << std::endl;
 std::cout <<"Date = "<< root["date"].asString() << std::endl;
 std::cout <<"Rate GBP ="<< root["rates"]["GBP"].asFloat() << std::endl;
 std::cout <<"Rate USD ="<< root["rates"]["USD"].asFloat() << std::endl;
```

The difference is that `std::endl` also calls `std::flush` on the stream. There is no need to flush the stream manually. The stream is designed to flush when it needs too. When you do it manually you will make your code much more eneficent.

#### RAII

```
 myHandle = curl_easy_init ( ) ;
 // STUFF
 curl_easy_cleanup( myHandle );
```

When you see this pattern. You should be thinking of using RAII. This will make sure your resources are cleaned up correctly in all situations (including when exceptions are thrown) are the function returns early (aka `return 1;`).